# Can 'Dupe' be used as a verb instead of 'Duplicate'?

Tags: verbs, american-english

I've seen this only in one scenario, 4 players on 2 teams are choosing which type of car they will use, and when both players on the same team choose the same car, player 1 says to player 2, 'Stop duping me!' or 'Don't dupe me'. The only source I can find to back up this usage is Dictionary.com, which presents no source or examples, but cites a Random House dictionary. Any thoughts?

Comment: Surely it ***can***, but *should* it?

Comment: "Dupe" is commonly used as a synonym/abbreviation for "duplicate" in informal communications.  However, "dupe" also means "fool" or "hoodwink".  I would suspect, given the above context, that this latter definition might have been intended.

Comment: "When cloning has been perfected, i'm going to dupe you"

Answer (score 10):

The Oxford Dictionary acknowledges *[dupe](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dupe#dupe-2)* as an abbreviation of *duplicate*:

> verb & noun
>
> Short for duplicate, especially in photography.
>   [AS VERB]: how to
>   dupe 35 mm slides on to 35 mm film
>   [AS NOUN]: black-and-white dupes

The application of *dupe* seems to be expanding beyond photography.